# rounded buttons of QMessageBox

Tags: qt, stylesheet

I am using a QMessagebox to ask if the user wants to close the application.

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent (QCloseEvent *event)
{
    QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;

    reply = QMessageBox::question(this, "Exit", "Are you sure you want to Exit?",
                                  QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No);
    if (reply == QMessageBox::Yes)
    {
        event->accept();
    } else {
        event->ignore();
    }
}
```

I am trying to round the Yes/No buttons by changing the stylesheet to

```
QMessageBox QPushButton{
border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px;
}
```

however this piece of code changes it to

[image: Rounded Buttons]

How do I make the rounded buttons a more proper size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not given it a definite size in the css rule; you have to define the `width` and `height` of the buttons or you you simply add a `padding` so the dimensions will *adjust relatively*.